# Hide and show a div based on a page loaded value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have this div hide or show depending on what `<%= ItemCount%>` is. If the number that comes up is less than five, I want the div to be hidden. If it is above 5, I want it to be visible. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

```
<div class="slideControl">
    <a id="slidesPrev" onclick="return false" href="#">
        <img src="/_assets/images/Arrowleft.png"
    </a>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;<%= ItemCount%>&nbsp;Total Products&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <a id="slidesNext" onclick="return false" href="#">
        <img src="/_assets/images/ArrowRight.png"
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: you can add this to div: `<div class=""slideControl" <%= (ItemCount <= 5) ? 'style="display:none;"' : '' %>`

Comment: Just a heads up . . . you are missing the closing tags `>` on your `<img>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is probably an aspx page you can try to use it inside a javascript function.

```
if (<%= ItemCount %> < 5) {
    $('.slideControl').hide();
}
```

And make sure that this javascript runs **after** page load.

Comment: How would you run this after the page loads. The value gets generated as the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. No need to do jquery. There are also many other variations you can do.

```
<div class="slideControl" style="<%= ItemCount < 5 ? "Display:None;" : ""%>">
```

Comment: This did not work and i got a Server Error from it. Does this work within a .Aspx file. This is where the code resides.

Comment: This should work within your aspx page. I tested it on an example I have and it worked. Make sure the rest of your code is well formed. Someone mentioned your missing closing tags. I also edited my code, one of the':' should have been a '?'

Comment: <div class="slideControl" style="<%= ItemCount < 5 ? "Display:None;" : ""%>">
   
       <a id="slidesPrev" onclick="return false" href="#"><img src="/_assets/images/Arrowleft.png"/></a>
       
       &nbsp;&nbsp;<%= ItemCount%>&nbsp;Total Products&nbsp;&nbsp;
       
       <a id="slidesNext" onclick="return false" href="#"><img src="/_assets/images/ArrowRight.png"/></a>
       
   </div>

Comment: Is ItemCount an integer? if not, you would have to do  Convert.ToInt32(ItemCount) < 5 ? "Display:None;" : ""

Comment: Also, what is the ItemCount currently outputting? Is it less than 5?

Comment: ItemCount is a number for the amount of products for that specific product page. It varies can be 1-Whatever. But usually less than 40.

Comment: If ItemCount is a number (int). Then the code should work. You could try ItemCount > 0 instead and just see if everything is hidden. Or try 0 == 0 and see if everything is hidden. Try a few cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that ended up working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        var itemCount = <%=ItemCount%>;
        if (itemCount < 5) {
            $("#productSlide").hide();
        }
    });
</script>


<div id="productSlide" class="slideControl">
                <a id="slidesPrev" onclick="return false" href="#">
                    <img src="/_assets/images/Arrowleft.png" /></a>

                &nbsp;&nbsp;<%= ItemCount%>&nbsp;Total Products&nbsp;&nbsp;

                        <a id="slidesNext" onclick="return false" href="#">
                            <img src="/_assets/images/ArrowRight.png" /></a>
</div>
```